# Interpolate in matlab

Tags: matlab

I  have two realizations for (X,Y)

(0, 200)
(23, 700)

I want to find the value of Y at X1=12.5 with matlab with linear interpolation

Would `interp1` work? but haven't figured out how to use the arguments

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the thing:

[image]

```matlab
x = [0,23];
y = [200,700];
xq = 12.5;
yq = interp1(x,y,xq)

%visualization
plot(x,y);hold on;
stem(xq,yq,'r')
```